# Sum of two sums in Ruby with two loops

Tags: ruby

If a pair of numbers in the array sums to zero, I want the positions of those two numbers. If no pair of numbers sums to zero, i should return `nil`.

The iteration not happening in my outer loop:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  # puts(nums)
  l = nums.length
  i = 0
  j = 1
  while(i < l)
    while(j < l)
      puts(nums[i] + nums[j])
      puts(nums[i])
      puts(nums[j])
      if(nums[i] + nums[j] == 0)
        return ("[" + i.to_s + "," + j.to_s + "]")
        puts("[" + i.to_s + "," + j.to_s + "]")
      else
        j = j + 1
      end
    end
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Note, you can't use `puts` following `return ...`. The `puts` will never be seen. Also, you can use `j += 1` and `i += 1` instead of `j = j + 1` and `i = i + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler to use ranges and `each`; this makes the code much clearer and more concise:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def two_sum(nums)
  (0...nums.length).each do |i|
    ((i+1)...nums.length).each do |j|
      return [i, j] if nums[i] + nums[j] == 0
    end
  end
  nil
end

p two_sum([1, 2, 3, -1, 4])  # [0, 3]
p two_sum([1, 2, 3])         # nil
p two_sum([])                # nil
```

Comment: This is clear but relatively inefficient, as it may require up to `nums.length*nums.length/2` calculations.

Comment: I was re-expressing the OP's original logic. The choice of implementation, your more efficient one for medium and large arrays vs. my simpler one, probably faster for smaller ones, depends on: 1) expected size of the input array, 2) how important speed is, 3) how important simplicity is, and 4) whether this is a real world production algorithm or an academic exercise (I suspect the latter).

Comment: Yes, I didn't express that well. If the array is not huge, efficiency is not an issue so it makes sense to go with an implementation that is easy to implement and understand, that is least likely to produce errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you set the value of `j = 1` only at the beginning, but you need it reset for each outer iteration. Just move the `j = 1` after the

```
while(i < l)
```

or even better: `j = i + 1`

Answer (score 1):

As ✅ has answered you question, I would like to suggest an alternative:

```
def pair_sums_to_zero(arr)
  h = arr.each_with_index.group_by { |n,_| n.abs }      
  return h[0].first(2).map(&:last) if h.key?(0) and h[0].size > 1
  a = h.map { |k,v| v.uniq(&:first) }.find { |b| b.size == 2 }
  a ? a.map(&:last) : nil
end

arr = [3,2,-4,-2,3,2]
pair_sums_to_zero arr
  #=> [1,3]
```

The steps:

```
  h = arr.each_with_index.group_by { |n,_| n.abs }
    #=> {3=>[[3, 0], [3, 4]], 2=>[[2, 1], [-2, 3], [2, 5]], 4=>[[-4, 2]]} 
  h.key?(0) and h[0].size > 1
    #=> false 
  c = h.map { |k,v| v.uniq(&:first) }
    #=> [[[3, 0]], [[2, 1], [-2, 3]], [[-4, 2]]]
  a = c.find { |b| b.size == 2 }
  a ? a.map(&:last) : nil
    #=> [[2, 1], [-2, 3]] 
  a ? a.map(&:last) : nil
    #=> [1, 3]
```

Another example:

```
arr = [3,0,2,-4,-6,0,3,0,2]
pair_sums_to_zero arr

h = arr.each_with_index.group_by { |n,_| n.abs }    
  #=> {3=>[[3, 0], [3, 6]], 0=>[[0, 1], [0, 5], [0, 7]], 2=>[[2, 2], [2, 8]],
  #    4=>[[-4, 3]], 6=>[[-6, 4]]} 
h.key?(0) and h[0].size > 1
  #=> true 
h[0].first(2).map(&:last)
  #=> [1, 5] (returned)
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a `combination(2)` solution, but I had to ask myself - is this easier to read than @Keith's simple approach. The answer was no .

Comment: True, @ndn, but as Keith pointed out, there are different needs for different situations.